# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[]

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm working in Entity Framework 6 for the first time. I downloaded the tutorial and used it to start my program. I'm using Entity Framework as a method of connecting to two different servers to pull data and store them in variables. I followed the tutuorial exactly and have it set up the exact same way. Below is what I have so far in the main module. If there's anything else you need to see, let me know. Hope this is enough info. Thanks!

```
    JobCodesContext = New LicensingRepository_DvlpEntities1

    Dim JobCodeQuery As ObjectQuery(Of ControlTrackedJobCode) =
        From Element In JobCodesContext.ControlTrackedJobCodes.Include("JobCode")
        Select Element
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1: Unable to cast from DbQuery to ObjectQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208709/entity-framework-4-1-unable-to-cast-from-dbquery-to-objectquery)

Comment: Potentially Lukas, but I don't know C#. Even though they are similar languages, I can't tell how that solution would help me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208709/entity-framework-4-1-unable-to-cast-from-dbquery-to-objectquery) converted to VB

```
Dim objectContext As ObjectContext = 
    CType(JobCodesContext, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

Dim JobCodeQuery As ObjectQuery(Of ControlTrackedJobCode) =
        From Element In objectContext.CreateObjectSet(Of ControlTrackedJobCode).Include("JobCode")
        Select Element
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas! I get the following error message: "'controlTrackedJobCodes is not a member of System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects" How do I add ControlTrackedJobCodes to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Objectcontext?

Comment: Try using `CreateObjectSet(Of ControlTrackedJobCode)` instead of `ControlTrackedJobCodes` ... not sure about the correct syntax in VB

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers