# How can I put a DbQuery's results into a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, combobox

I've been following Microsoft's [walkthrough on how to use Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386884(v=vs.100).aspx), but I get the following exception when trying to put a query's results into a combobox:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[SchoolEF.Department]' to
>   type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'."

After searching on stackoverflow I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208709/entity-framework-4-1-unable-to-cast-from-dbquery-to-objectquery) answer to a similar problem, but I don't know how to use the solutions given in the context of my program since Execute isn't in `DbQuery` and I need a DbContext to access the database.

Below is the concerning code, where SchoolEntities extends DbContext and departmentList is a ComboBox.

```
private void CourseViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            schoolContext = new SchoolEntities();

            var departmentQuery = from d in schoolContext.Departments.Include("Courses")
                                  orderby d.Name
                                  select d;

            this.departmentList.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.departmentList.DataSource = ((ObjectQuery)departmentQuery).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 //...
 this.departmentList.DataSource =departmentQuery.ToList();
```

You don't need to do that cast to set the `DataSource`. Just call `ToList` extension method to materialize the result of your query. Also you should set `ValueMember`:

```
this.departmentList.ValueMember = "Id";// PK of department entity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.departmentList.DataSource = ((ObjectQuery)departmentQuery).Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
this.departmentList.DataBind();
```

Probably just lacking the dataBind instrction. I don't know how you put your data source in your combo box though.