# How to compare datetimeoffset ? Entity Framework query - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am new to Entity Framework and Linq in C#. In my code, I want to get data by comparing DateTimeOffset `fromTime` which is coming from datepicker. and `EvenDateUTC` is my database column name.
but its showing error: `Specified cast is not valid.`
please help what I am misssing.

my C# code is :-

```
if (fromTime.HasValue)
                {
                    var tmp = new DateTimeOffset(fromTime.Value.ToUniversalTime());
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.EventDateUTC >= tmp);
                }
```

in Sql query

```
( CAST( [Extent1].[EventDateUTC] AS datetimeoffset) >= @p__linq__0)
```

in sql: it showing error: `Must declare the scalar variable "@p__linq__0".`

Comment: Sorry I can't help you. When I use the code provided I get a completely different error. There must be something else to reproduce?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208709/entity-framework-4-1-unable-to-cast-from-dbquery-to-objectquery

@Watcher i think its like this ^^ issue. but I did understand how to solve this